# SQL Server Backup Database over ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm trying to write a program that is able to import and export a specific database, plus users and logins, from a Microsoft SQL Server database. I have an abstraction layer between my code and ODBC that much of our other software uses. The abstraction layer normally runs with autocommit off and handles transactions on its own, but since the BACKUP command doesn't like being run in any transaction, I"m using another method of the layer, called executeDirect, that runs it with autocommit on.

The method uses the SQLExecDirect function to run the BACKUP command. When it's done, the function returns SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, since the BACKUP command likes to give three lines of output. The code then attempts to get the output with SQLGetDiagField and is able to gather the first line from record #1, but there is no record #2.

The last thing the method wants to do is reset the connection to autocommit off, but when it attempts that, an error occurs, saying "Connection is busy with results from another command", SQL State is "HY000". So, obviously, the connection wants to remit the other two lines of output, but I don't know how to let it do so.

Answer (score 1):

The BACKUP DATABASE command works as a batch, requiring a call to SQLMoreResults to continue with the backup.